# If $f(f(n))+f(n)=2n+2014$, find $f$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> Let the function $f:\mathbb N^{+}\to\mathbb N^{+}$ such 
>   $$f(f(n))+f(n)=2n+2014.$$
>
> Find $f$.

My try: let $n=1$, then we have
$$f(f(1))+f(1)=2016$$
let $f(1)=a$,then
$$f(a)+a=2016$$
and let $n=a$, then
$$f(f(a))+f(a)=2a+2014$$
so
$$f(2016-a)+2016-a=2a+2014$$
so$$ f(2016-a)=3a-2$$
then I can't. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

There is no such function. (**Edit:** This is a simplification of the original argument.)

The functional equation implies that $f(f(n))\leq2n+2014$ holds for all $n$. Inductively define a sequence $a_0=1$ and $a_n=f(a_{n-1})$ for $n>0$. Observe:

**Lemma.** For all $n$, we have $a_{2n}\leq 2015\cdot 2^n-2014$.

*Proof.* We prove this by induction. It is true for $n=0$. Suppose it is true for $n-1$. Then $$a_{2n}=f(f(a_{2n-2}))\leq 2a_{2n-2}+2014\leq2(2015\cdot2^{n-1}-2014)+2014=2015\cdot 2^n-2014.$$ This completes the proof. $\square$

On the other hand, our sequence satisfies a recurrence: $$a_n+a_{n-1}=f(f(a_{n-2}))+f(a_{n-2})=2a_{n-2}+2014\qquad (n\geq2)$$ This has a [unique solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RSolve[%7Ba[n]%20%3D%3D%202%20a[n%20-%202]%20-%20a[n%20-%201]%20%2B%202014%2C%20a[0]%20%3D%3D%201%2C%20a[1]%20%3D%3D%20A%7D%2C%20%20%20a[n]%2C%20n]) (with $a_0=1$ and $a_1=a:=f(1)$) $$a_n=\frac19(-2008+(2017-3a)(-2)^n+3a+6042n).$$

But $2017$ is not divisible by $3$, so the coefficient of $(-2)^n$ is nonzero. This is a contradiction, since $4^n=(-2)^{2n}$ grows faster than $2^n$, contradicting our lemma.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full solution, but hopefully a useful contribution:

Begin with the guess that $f(n) = an + b$, for $a,b \in \Bbb Z$.  We have
$$
f(f(n)) + f(n) = 2n + 2014 \implies\\
(a^2+a)n + (a+2)b = 2n + 2014 \implies\\
\begin{cases}
a^2 + a = 2\\
(a+2)b = 2014
\end{cases}
$$
Solving the first equation yields $a \in \{1,-2\}$, but only $a=1$ can work with the second equation.  So, we have
$$
b = 2014/(1+2) = 2014/3 \notin \Bbb Z
$$
which seems to indicate that no such $f$ (i.e. no $f(n) = an + b$) exists.

In addition: if $f(n)$ is a polynomial of (finite) degree greater than $1$, then $f(f(n)) + f(n)$ must also be such a polynomial, ruling out the equality in question.

So, it seems that $f$ cannot be any polynomial on $n$ (though perhaps a valid power series exists?).

Comment: if you assumed f(n) was a linear function

Comment: Right.  So, this shows that no satisfactory "linear" $f$ exists.

Comment: but that means $f(x)$ can be amy polynomial of degree $> 1$

Comment: @VarunIyer in fact, this is not the case.  If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $>1$, then so is $f(f(n)) + f(n)$, which rules out the functional equality in question.

Comment: oh I understand now, sorry, I didn't catch that equality was linear.

Answer (score 1):

Using matrix algebra.

Let $a_0=a$, and $a_n=f\circ f\circ f\circ \ldots\circ f(a)$ where $f$ is taken $n$ times.

Then for any $n\ge 1$ we have $a_{n+1}+a_n=2a_{n-1}+2014$, or

$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+1} \\ a_n \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 2014 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} a_n \\ a_{n-1} \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\ldots=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 2 & 2014 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix} f(a) \\ a \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$

Next, you simply consider the Jordan form of the $3\times 3$ matrix, and easily find the following expression:

$a_n=\frac{3a(2+(-2)^n)+3f(a)(1-(-2)^n)+2014(3n-1+(-2)^n)}{9}$ $=\frac{a-f(a)+2014/3}{3}(-2)^n+\frac{2014}{3}n+\frac{2a+f(a)-2014/3}{3}$

and the first term will dominate at some point, making $a_n$ negative for an odd $n$. So, there is no such function.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a simplification (and then generalization to make it complicated again) of* Dejan Gove's *answer.*

**Claim.** Let $A\in\mathbb N^+$, $B\in \mathbb Z$. Let $f\colon \mathbb N^+\to \mathbb N^+$ be a function with $f(f(n))+f(n)=An+B$ for all $n\in\mathbb N^+$. Then 
$$\frac{2B}{\sqrt{4A+1}+3} $$
is an integer.

*Proof.* Let $f$ be such a function and define recursively $a_{n+1}=f(a_n)$ (with $a_0\in\mathbb N^+$ arbitrary). Then the functional equation reads
$$\tag1 a_{n+2}+a_{n+1}=Aa_n+B$$
If $A\ne2$ we can let $b_n:=a_n+\frac{B}{A-2}\in\mathbb Q$ and obtain
$$\tag2b_{n+2}=-b_{n+1}+Ab_n$$
which is well-known to have solutions of the form
$$b_n=\alpha_1 \lambda_1^n+\alpha_2\lambda_2^n$$
where $\lambda_{1,2}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1+4A}}{2}$ are the (distinct real) roots of $X^2+X-A=0$ and $\alpha_{1,2}\in\mathbb R$ can be determined from the first two terms.
Note that $|\lambda_2|=|\lambda_1|+1>1$. Hence if $\alpha_2\ne0$ then for $n\gg0$ we will have $|\alpha_2\lambda_2^n|>2\cdot |\alpha_1\lambda_1^n|$ and as $\lambda_2$ is negative we have $b_n\ll 0$ for large $n$ of suitable parity. But then also $a_n<0$, contradiction.
Therefore $\alpha_2=0$ and $b_n=\alpha_1\lambda_1^n$. 
Then $\lambda_1=\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$ is rational, $4A+1$ is a perfect (odd) square, so that finally $\lambda_1\in\mathbb N^+$.
From $b_{n+1}=\lambda_1b_n$ we find 
$$ a_{n+1}=\lambda_1a_n+\frac{(\lambda_1-1)B}{A-2}$$
We conclude that $$ \frac{(\lambda_1-1)B}{A-2}=\frac{(\sqrt{4A+1}-3)B}{2(A-2)}=\frac{2B}{\sqrt{4A+1}+3}$$
is an integer.

If $A=2$, we can let $b_n=a_n-\frac{Bn}3$ instead and obtain $(2)$ again, with solutions of the form $b_n=\alpha_1(-2)^n+\alpha_2$ so that again $a_n=\alpha_1(-2)^n+\alpha_2+\frac{Bn}3\ll 0 $  for $n$ large enough of suitable parity - unless $\alpha_2=0$. We conclude $a_n=\alpha_2+\frac{Bn}{3}$ so that $\frac B3=a_{n+1}-a_n$ is an integer. $_\square$

**Corollary.** If a function as above exists, then $A=(d-1)(d-2)$ for a divisor $d\mid B$ with $d\ge3$. Specifically, if $A=2$ then $3\mid B$.

*Proof.* This follows from writing $4A+1$ as odd perfect square. $_\square$